# Function Relation

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are linear in some dual space of polynomial and $f(a)=0$ implies $g(a)=0$ for $a$ in vector space correspondents with the dual space. Prove $f=\lambda g$ for $\lambda$ constant.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I mean in dual space, I'll fix it

Comment: You are given $\langle f\rangle^{\circ}\subseteq\langle g\rangle^{\circ}$ and want to prove $\langle g\rangle\subseteq\langle f\rangle$.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? @ancientmathematician

Comment: See below for my best effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that we have here a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ and its dual space $V^{*}$. For any $X\leqslant V$ (subspace this means) we have $X^{\circ}:=\{f\in V^{*} | f(x)= 0 \text{ for all $x\in X$}\}$; and for any $H\leqslant V^{*}$ we have $H^{\circ}:=\{v\in V | h(v)= 0 \text{ for all $h\in H$}\}$.

It is clear that $U_1\leqslant U_2$ implies $U_2^{\circ}\leqslant U_1^{\circ}$; and it is a standard result that $U^{\circ\circ}=U$ and $H^{\circ\circ}=H$.

Suppose $f,g\in V^{*}$. Note that $f(a)=0$ if and only if $(\mu f)(a)=0$ for all $\mu$; in other words $f(a)=0$ if and only if $a\in \langle f\rangle^{\circ}$.

So our hypothesis is $\langle f\rangle^{\circ}\leqslant \langle g\rangle^{\circ}$. Hence $\langle f\rangle^{\circ\circ}\geqslant \langle g\rangle^{\circ\circ}$; that is $\langle f\rangle\geqslant\langle g\rangle$. Hence for some $\lambda$ (Lagrange's multiplier!) we have $g=\lambda f$.

**NOTE** The question as stated is false; with $g=0$ we will get the result I have proved, but not necessarily the result stated in the question.

Comment: NOTE The question as stated is false; with g=0g=0 we will get the result I have proved, but not necessarily the result stated in the question.                                                                            Can I know why? Sorry I can't cite

Comment: @Laurence: Take any non-zero $f$ at all, and take $g=0$. The pair $f,g$ satisfy the hypothesis, yet $f\not=0=\lambda g$.